# Blazor component availability moment

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

*NOTE: In this question I make use of a [specific component](https://github.com/welisonmenezes/wm-blazor-slick-carousel), but I guess my issue is related to my general approach to blazor pages rather than this specific component.*

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app with the following page:

**page.razor**

```
@page "/mypage"

<h3>Title</h3>

<BlazorSlickCarousel @ref="carVp" Configurations="carVpConf">
    <BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
    </BlazorSlickCarouselContent>
    <BlazorSlickCarouselLoading>
    </BlazorSlickCarouselLoading>
</BlazorSlickCarousel>
```

**page.razor.cs**

```
using WMBlazorSlickCarousel.WMBSC;

private BlazorSlickCarousel carVp;
private WMBSCInitialSettings carVpConf;

private bool cond = true;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    carVpConf = new WMBSCInitialSettings(){ /* some options */ };
}

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (cond)
    {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    else
    {
        /* await time consuming task */
    }
    await PopulateCarousel();
}

public async Task PopulateCarousel()
{
    var div = $@"<div class='vs-container'>Some stuff</div>";
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        await carVp.Add(div);
    }
}
```

If `cond == true`, `PopulateCarousel()` behaviour is unpredictable: sometimes an ArgumentNullException is thrown, sometimes not all divs are added to the carousel.

If `cond == false`, everything is working.

I guess that when `cond == true` the carVp component is not yet (fully) created/initialized.
In fact, if I add a little delay to the first `If` branch (with `await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));` everything is fine.

The question is: where should I put my call to `PopulateCarousel()` to be sure that the component is fully created and initialized? Is there a (generic) way to check for component state?

I tried with `OnInitializedAsync`, `OnAfterRenderAsync` and `OnAfterRender`, but none of them worked.

Thank you!

Comment: Try calling StateHasChanged at the end of PopulateCarousel - you get one re-render on the first await, after that you have to explicitly call it.

Comment: `"you get one re-render on the first await, after that you have to explicitly call it."` Your conclusion is wrong, and no call to StateHasChanged should be manually coded.

Comment: @enet I disagree with your conclusion.

Comment: It's your prerogative...

Answer (score 2):

The component life cycle events are fired in following sequence

OnInitialized ----->OnParametersSet----->OnAfterRender

As you said "to be sure that the component is fully created and initialized?". OnAfterRender event is fired when component UI is fully rendered and is available for access and updates.